# windows C++ simulating emoji input to a browser window - scrambled chars

Tags: c++, windows, unicode, utf-8, emoji

I am using Visual Studio Community 2022 to build a windows C++ app that is trying to basically copy paste with one method or another a line from a text file into a Chrome browser's text field.

I have a UTF-8 encoded .txt file containing a sentence per line with an emoji at the end.

A sample emoji that I'm trying to use:

I read it into a vector or vector with code like: (I have tried both wstrings and strings)

```
    ifstream infile("Lines.txt");
    if(!infile.is_open()) return false;

    string aLine;
    // Read the database
    while (getline(infile, aLine))
    {
        theDB.push_back(aLine);
    }

    infile.close();

    return !theDB.empty();
```

I have then tried to send it with
SendMessage(aWindow, WM_CHAR, aCharacter, 0);

and by copying it to the clipboard and then pasting it from there. (In both CF_TEXT and CF_UNICODETEXT format, with a method that I've used successfully for plain text and Spanish letters.)

I have also tried adding /utf8 in the compiler options.

No matter what the emojis always get scrambled, but with most settings the rest of the text works fine.

Comment: Windows are expecting either MBCS (codepage) or UTF-16le text - depends on the application.

Comment: Did you read the documentation for [`WM_CHAR`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-char)? To send an emoji (or any Unicode character outside of ASCII, for that matter), you would have to send it as separate UTF-16 surrogates (ie, `0x2DDD 0xD83E` for U+1F92D), but only if the receiving window is a Unicode window. Otherwise, use [`WM_UNICHAR`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-unichar) instead.

Comment: It seems If I use wstrings and theDB.push_back(L"Hey "); without loading from a text file - that works with WM_CHAR even. I can't even edit my question for some reason.

Comment: It would work, because when you're not using a file the emoji is not UTF-8 encoded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert your utf8 to wchar, luckily Windows has the `MultiByteToWideChar` function to help you with this, you'll then be able to copy to clipbaord using `CF_UNICODETEXT`.

Here's the function I use.

```
wchar_t* utf8toWChar(const char* utf8string)
{
    const int buffsize = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, utf8string, -1, nullptr, 0);

    wchar_t* gah = static_cast<wchar_t*>(malloc((buffsize + 1) * sizeof(wchar_t)));

    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, utf8string, -1, gah, buffsize);
    gah[buffsize] = 0;

    return gah;
}
```

And here's the C++ version:

```
std::wstring utf8towstring(const std::string& utf8string)
{
   if (utf8string.empty())
   {
       return std::wstring();
   }

   int charactersWritten = ::MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, utf8string.data(), (int)utf8string.size(), NULL, 0);
   if (0 == charactersWritten)
   { 
       return std::wstring();
   }

   std::wstring str2;
   str2.resize(charactersWritten);

   charactersWritten = ::MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, utf8string.data(), (int)utf8string.size(), &str2[0], str2.capacity());
   if (0 == charactersWritten)
   {
      return std::wstring();
   }

   return str2;
}
```

Reading from UTF-8 encoded text file, converted using utf8towstring, and then copieg to clipboard:

Output: trying to use:  That worked!

Comment: Why use `malloc()` in C++? You can just preallocate a `std::wstring` and convert directly into it. Alternatively, since you know the file is UTF-8, you can just use `std::wifstream` instead with a UTF-8 locale `imbue()`'d into it and then read its lines into `std::wstring` strings.

Comment: I had tried your suggestion before posting, but could not get this approach to work, getline seems to stop at the first encounter of an emoji however the posted answer worked and maintained emoji.

Comment: This method works for me even with WM_CHAR. Thank you!

Comment: @user20716902 then you probably just didn't use it correctly. In any case, in your updated answer, `&str2[0]` can be `str2.data()` in C++17 and later, and `str2.capacity()` should be `str2.size()`.